# Can't create a new blob container in NativeScript

Tags: azure, nativescript, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the NativeScript library here https://github.com/dzfweb/nativescript-azure-storage and trying to create a new blob container but I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: azureStorage.createBlobContainer is not a function. (In 'azureStorage.createBlobContainer('blobContainer')', 'azureStorage.createBlobContainer' is undefined)
```

My code is:

```
let azureStorage = new NativeScriptAzureStorage(this.connectionString);
azureStorage.createBlobContainer('blobContainer')
   .then(() => console.log(`Blog container Created!`))
   .catch((err) => console.log(`Error creating blob container: ${err}`));
```

and I am using the connection string generated by the blob object from Azure.

```
'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=x;AccountKey=x;
```

I've also tried adding the blobEndpoint but that didn't work either.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is it Android or iOS, you are facing this issue?

Comment: iOS using Preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use **nativescript-azure-storage** plugin with Preview app. Use `tns run` instead, that requires a complete environment setup on your local machine to build the app.

> The Preview app comes with a predefined set of NativeScript plugins.
>   If your app utilizes a plugin that is not present in the Preview app,
>   you will see a warning message and your app might not work as
>   expected.

Source: [from docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview#command-limitations)

Comment: Still does not work even when building the app in release mode to ios device. Getting the same error.

Comment: What you mean by still doesn't work? Did you create a new project and used `tns run`? If still fails, please share the sample project where the issue can be reproduced.